# Numpy : save multiple arrays using savez in npz format in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

so I am trying to save multiple numpy arrays that get generated one after the other in a loop in one npz file
I cannot pass them to the function all at once, I know that if I had them in separate variables I could but they are generated one by one in a loop and are too many to be concatenated into one array.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about a separate `savez` for each group of arrays? There may be a tool for merging `zip` archives, but even if there isn't, working with several `npz` archives shouldn't be any less efficient than with just one large one.  It may even be more convenient.

Comment: we will be reading those in the loss function in a neural network, having 20k I/O operations will slow down the training time significantly